# There is possible to return "100 Continue" using slim3 Framework?

Tags: rest, http-response-codes, slim-3

I should handle the receiving header "Expect: 100-continue" responding "100 Continue". Then after perform some logic the new return must be "200 Success" or something else.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to return 2 responses for 1 request or did I get you wrong?

Comment: @danopz You got it! I think that's it. "The client should continue with the request or ignore it if it is already finished" [more...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/100).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can only send one response per request